# Offtopic? List of all (pseudo) apostrophic and question marky signs

Tags: discussion, question-quality, questions

Would a question to list all UTF8-signs that could be mistaken for or are curly forms of quotation marks and apostrophes be considered off-topic?

E.g. `` `´’ `` instead of `'` and

`“”„“` instead for `"`

I'd need it for a search-and-replace-regex.

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic comment, but as you practically already asked it, here's a hint for a starting point: http://copypastecharacter.com/punctuation

Comment: i'm not sure you've really adequately asked this meta question. for one, i have no idea what you're even asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that has no connection to Unix and Linux (despite what you plan to use it for). It might be on-topic on [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/), they allow [punctuation](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) questions, but "list all X" questions tend not to go well anywhere on Stack Exchange

Comment: Yeah, I thought so.Though I would argue that it is not a "list anyting" kind of question, but more of a specific "name whole set", which is fixed, but not universally known.